# Пункт меню съезжает на вторую строчку

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет. Есть [сайт](http://www.doverie2u.com.ua), у которого проблема с верхним меню. Последний пункт меню съезжает на вторую строчку. Как это устранить? В самом браузере у меня все получается, убираю `margin-right: 7px;`. Но когда прописываю в CSS, все остается, как было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На моем мониторе (1024px) вниз уходят два пункта меню.
Если надо, чтобы они всегда были в ряд, то:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>

ul {
white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Но тогда полоса прокрутки будет появляться.

Здесь есть несколько вариантов решения в зависимости от Вашего дизайна:
1. Самый простой - при уменьшении ширины экрана выравниваете меню в два ряда по центру страницы. Это просто, но некрасиво.
2. Делаете видимый сайдбар (справа или слева контента) с  пунктами меню, которые не помещаются в основное меню. 
3. Самый модный вариант - делаете [off-canvas меню](https://github.com/OlgaMaraeva/off-canvas-menu-translate).

Любой вариант годиться, лишь бы не так, как сейчас, - на мобильной версии по клику выпадает меню для широкоэкранных мониторов, гле пункты выравниваются горизонтально.

Еще проще - прикрутите Fixed to top [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) Bootstrap.

Можно отвоевать ширину меню еще несколькими способами:
 - уменьшить шрифт (он очень крупный);
 - "задать вопрос специалисту" - убрать в плавающую панель сбоку от страницы (так обычно делается) или прижать к низу; 
 - контакты можно поместить в футер.

[Здесь](http://www.napaautocare.com/) можно посмотреть на живом примере. Правда, они схитрили немножко - на определенном промежутке оставили горизонтальную прокрутку.

Comment: @Olga Moscow а как сделать так, чтобы меню оставалось адаптивным?

Comment: отредактировала ответ

Answer (score 1):

Есть одна такая фишка, которая дает свойству наивысший приоритет. 
Например, `margin-right: 7px !important;`.
Рекомендовано не злоупотреблять.
А вообще в вашей ситуации я бы предпочел уменшить  padding по селектору `a`, тогда проблема решиться сама собой.

Comment: @matthale_ua То есть у всех ссылок меню убрать правый padding?

Comment: Не только справа. В целом.
И у вас текст на кнопке при уменшение окна браузера выпадает.
Попробуйте navbar-nav > li > a {width:100% }

Comment: @matthale_ua пробую, но ничего не меняется, даже с использованием !important. Как узнать, какое правило перекрывает?

Comment: Я пользуюсь DevTools в Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I). Можно Firebug'ом в Firefox.
Можно ПКМ по кнопке, и там выбрать "проверить элемент". Справа в окошке будут стили, и путь к файлам, в которых они прописаны.